# JTree selection color

Tags: java, swing, selection, jtree

I'm using a JTree in my application. If I select a leaf node in most of the cases they are displayed with blue background (which is fine). But for some reason in some cases they do not get a blue background (though the event handling for choosing this leaf node works). I don't have a clue what could be the problem here... If I expand or collapse a branch node after the selection (with the little icon in front of a branch node), the selection becomes visible. I'm pretty confused by this behaviour.
Any idea where to start digging into this problem?

Comment: sounds like a bug - most probably in your code. First guess is a repaint issue, that is no repaint triggered for whatever reason. To check that assumption, add a button somewhere which forces a repaint without doing anything else. Next time the issue appears, press  the button - if nothing happens, you have to look somewhere else: the node actually is _not_ selected, something's wrong with the selection logic. If it now is painted correctly, there's a notification issue somewhere - the node is selected but the state change not passed on to the tree

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint! I called the repaint method at the end of my selection listener 'valueChanged' and realized that the end of this method was never reached due to a RuntimeException which has been thrown for some of the leaf nodes. Handling the exception instead solved the issue.

Comment: hmm, now I cannot mark this issue as solved as I'm not allowed to answer my own questions...

Answer (score 0):

JTree uses (unless you changed the L&F) the `BasicTreeUI` which in turn will use the `DefaultTreeCellRenderer`. If you look at the method `getTreeCellRendererComponent` this might help you. If it's easy to replicate this issue some debugging into this method might reveal the cause.

Comment: I've overridden the cell renderer and it works fine on 'Metal' L&F, but on GTK+, it looks like it uses my renderer in addition to another renderer, and it behaves strange. Is there a way to prevent the L&F affect?